# Get all VCS changes between previous and current build

Tags: teamcity

How can I get all VCS changes between previous and current build? I need to get all commit messages of current branch in one of build steps.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all changes, included in current build, via TeamCity REST API. Just make GET request to url

```
 http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(id:<buildId>)
```

More details available in [the documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-Changes)